# prove that a function whose derivative is bounded also bounded

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I got this problem:

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $f'$ (the derivative of $f$) is bounded on $(a,b)$ (meaning there exist $0<M$ such that $\forall x\in(a,b), |f'(x)|\leq M$), Prove that $f$ is also bounded on $(a,b)$.

I tried to prove it but wasn't able to proceed.
Thanks.

Comment: If a function goes to infinity, its slope will also increase to infinity to get to infinity within finite distance. See a graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix a point $x_0\in (a,b).$ Assume $x\in(x_0,b).$ By using the Lagrange's theorem there exists $c\in(x_0,x)$ such that $f(x)-f(x_0)=f'(c)(x-x_0).$ Thus

$$|f(x)|=|f(x_0)+f'(c)(x-x_0)|\leq |f(x_0)|+|f'(c)||(x-x_0)|\leq |f(x_0)|+M(b-a).$$ Proceeding in the same way you get the bound for $x\in(a,x_0).$ Thus we have shown that the function is bounded.

**Edit:**
If $x=x_0$ then we have the bound: $|f(x_0)|\le |f(x_0)|+M(b-a).$

Comment: why do you need to make assumptions whether $x\in (x_0,b)$ ?

Comment: @G.T.R Just to not worry about signs and relative order. In fact if $x\in(a,x_0)$, the only difference is that $c\in(x,x_0)$.

Comment: Maybe it is also worth mentioning why the bound holds for $x = x_0$. You do not seem to cover this case? :)

Comment: @Nikolaj Case $x=x_0$ covered. Thanks for noticing it.