# Show a function whose derivative is bounded is also bounded in an interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose g is differentiable over (a,b] (i.e. g is defined and differentiable over (a,c), where (a,c)$\supset$(a,b]), and |g'(p)|$\le$ M (M is a real number) for all p in (a,b]. Prove that |g(p)|$\le$Q for some real number over (a,b].

I looked at a similar solution here: [prove that a function whose derivative is bounded also bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805439/prove-that-a-function-whose-derivative-is-bounded-also-bounded)
but I'm not sure if they are asking the same thing, and I'm having trouble figuring out the case when $x\in(a,x_0)$ (x here is point p). Could someone give a complete proof of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mean value theorem to get $g(x) = (x - b)g'(c) + g(b)$. If $x$ is bounded then clearly the RHS of the equation is bounded.

Comment: How to show that the RHS of the equation is bounded in (a,b]?

Comment: Show that $|x-b||g'(c)|+ |g(b)| \le Q=M(b-a) + |g(b)|$.

Comment: @Emma: the part $g'(c)$ is bounded because derivative is bounded. The part $g(b)$ is fixed constant. The only part remaining is $(x - b)$. This is bounded when $x$ is also bounded. Now $x$ is bounded because we have $x \in (a, b]$ and thus $a < x \leq b$. So the RHS is bounded.

Comment: Thanks, I get that the RHS is bounded, but how to show Q is in (a,b]?

Comment: @Emma: $Q$ is not required to be in $(a, b]$. If that is a part of your question then consider it as a typo. The conclusion should be "$|g(p)| \leq Q$ for all numbers $p \in (a, b]$ and some real number number $Q$".

Comment: I think I get it, thanks a lot!