# Show a differentiable function has value of zero

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $g$ is differentiable over $[a,b], g(a)=0$, $|g'(p)|\le Q|g(p)|$ over $[a,b]$ for some constant $Q$, show that $g=0$ over $[a,b]$.

I was thinking about using the properties in the following link, [Show a function whose derivative is bounded is also bounded in an interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543840/show-a-function-whose-derivative-is-bounded-is-also-bounded-in-an-interval)
but not sure how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Is this not just simple application of Gronwall's inequality ?

Comment: @Leandro Haven't learned the integral application yet so not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $x_0\in [a,b]$ let $M_0=\sup |f(x)|$, $M_1=\sup |f'(x)|$ for $[a,x_0]$. For any such $x$, $$|f(x)|\leqslant M_1(x_0-a)\leqslant A(x_0-a)M_0$$ Hence $M_0=0$ if $A(x_0-a)<1.$ That is, $f=0$ on $[a,x_0]$. Proceed this process.

Comment: I don't get why $|f(x)|\leqslant M_1(x_0-a)$, and why is  $M_0=0$ if $A(x_0-a)<1.$

Comment: Use mean value theorem to $f(x)$ on interval $[a,x]$ where $f(a)=0$

Comment: Thanks, and why is  $M_0=0$ if $A(x_0-a)<1.$?

Comment: @Emma, Suppose $M_0\neq 0$ then $|f(x)|\le A(x_0-a)M_0<M_0=\sup |f(x)|$. We get contradiction because in this case constant $A(x_0-a)M_0$ which is less that $\sup$ is upper bound.

Comment: Yes of course. In my solution $A=Q$. We have shown that if $A(x_0-a)<1$ then $f=0$ on $[a,x_0]$. We know that $A>0$ (because the case $A=0$ is obvious). Then $x_0<a+1/A$$\Rightarrow$ so you can take $x_0=\frac{1}{2}(a+1/A)$ and make this process to new interval $[x_0,x_1]$ and so on. After finite steps you get that $f\equiv 0$ on $[a,b]$.